# How to highlight selected Faces in Texture Paint?

Tags: mesh, uv, interface, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

Is there a way the left panel can highlight the selected faces on the right just so I can track where I am paint? Switching ack and forth between UV Editor and Texture Paint doesn't do it either.

[image]

Comment: weird because in the Image Editor, by default you only see the faces you've selected in the 3D view... maybe share your file? (or a part of it) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I am unable to upload the file into your link. Here's the file anyway. https://mega.nz/file/MgxlgYoI#qyc0CpanKAiSckvphFP_Eead9EUyk1-lwOZsARKDa3I

Answer (score 0):

In the *UV Editor*, disable the *Sync UV* option:

[image]

And in the *Image Editor*, enable the *View > Display Texture Paint UVs* option:

[image]

Comment: Ah ok... thank you! :)